# How to programatically compare permissions of login/user in SQL Server 2005

Tags: t-sql

There's a login/user in SQL Server  who is having a problem importing accounts in production server. I don't have an idea what method he is doing this. According to the one importing, this import is working fine in development server. But when he did the same import in production it is giving him errors. Below are the errors he is getting for each accounts.

```
2009-06-05 18:01:05.8254 ERROR [engine-1038] Task [1038:00001 - Members]: Step 1.0 [<Insert step description>]: Task.RunStep(): StoreRow has failed
2009-06-05 18:01:05.9035 ERROR [engine-1038] Task [1038:00001 - Members]: Step 1.0 [<Insert step description>]: Task.RunStep(): StoreRow exception:  Exception caught while storing Data. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]'ACCOUNT1' is not a valid login or you do not have permission.
```

Please note that 'ACCOUNT1' is not the real account name. I just changed it for security reason.

Using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), I viewed/checked the permissions of the user/login who is performing the import from development server and production for comparison. I found no difference.

My question is: Is there a way to programmatically query permissions in server and database level of a particular login/user so I can compare/contrast for any differences?

Answer (score 2):

Red Gate's SQL Compare wil do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

This code shows all the rights that the login has.

```
select sys.schemas.name 'Schema', sys.objects.name Object, sys.database_principals.name username, sys.database_permissions.type permissions_type,
    sys.database_permissions.permission_name,
    sys.database_permissions.state permission_state,
    sys.database_permissions.state_desc,
    state_desc + ' ' + permission_name + ' on ['+ sys.schemas.name + '].[' + sys.objects.name + '] to [' + sys.database_principals.name + ']' COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AS
from sys.database_permissions
join sys.objects on sys.database_permissions.major_id =
    sys.objects.object_id
join sys.schemas on sys.objects.schema_id = sys.schemas.schema_id
join sys.database_principals on sys.database_permissions.grantee_principal_id =
    sys.database_principals.principal_id
order by 1, 2, 3, 5
```

Comment: You should join to `sys.all_objects` and use `left join` throughout, as now you are missing database level permissions and system objects.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use

```
sp_helplogins '<loginname>'
```

See the MSDN reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190304.aspx).